# JSF - Why is the Instance of SessionScoped class not initialized?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, managed-bean

I wan't to display the values of my enumeration class [license] in a selectOneMenue.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="licenseclassmenue" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="select license"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{licenseCodes.licenseCodes}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu><br />
```

my licenseCode Class:

```
/**
 * convert enum to array of strings
 * 
 * */
@ManagedBean(name = "licenseCodes" )
@SessionScoped
public class LicenseCodes {

public SelectItem[] getLicenseCodes() {
    SelectItem[] licenses = new SelectItem[License.values().length];
    int i = 0;
    for (License l : License.values()) {
        licenses[i++] = new SelectItem(l, l.name());
    }
    return licenses;
}

}
```

The enum

```
public enum License {
A("A"),B("B"),C("C");

    private String value;

    private License(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    };

}
```

When I deploy the project, there won't be any licenses in the selectOneMenue.
During debugging I noticed that getLicenseCodes() is never be called.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you add a `h:outputText` with value mapped with a `String` field of your managed bean, then the constructor get called? What about using `@PostConstruct` method to initialize the `SelectItems`?

Comment: I just added an @PostConstruct to initialize a SelectItem[] field and debugged the Session. It's not called.

Comment: Also I just added a String and h:outputText won't show anything

Comment: The `@ManagedBean` is from `javax.faces.bean` package, right? You did rebuild/redeploy/restart after adding the class, right?

Comment: @BalusC +1. we don't think he is using `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` otherwise (name="licenseCodes") would gave him compile time error.

Comment: I tried both possible packages. Also I restarted the Jboss every time I made a change to the code. I'm using annotations, my faces-config doesn't contain any info about managed-beans

Comment: Is the bean class in a package? Do other managed beans work fine?

Comment: yes. I have a second bean in an different package. I can show the data of the beans fields without any problem.

Comment: I have another question. *Why* is it session-scoped? It's read-only, so it should be application-scoped.

Comment: For no reason so far. Later it might be session-scoped because I have differend types of user and the will get different licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your class:

```
package so.question14163260;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

@ManagedBean(name = "licenseCodes")
@SessionScoped
public class LicenseCodes {

    private SelectItem[] licenses;

    public LicenseCodes() {
        System.out.println("================Inside===============");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SelectItem[] licenses = new SelectItem[License.values().length];
        int i = 0;
        for (License l : License.values()) {
            licenses[i++] = new SelectItem(l, l.name());
        }

        setLicenses(licenses);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getLicenses() {
        return licenses;
    }

    public void setLicenses(SelectItem[] licenses) {
        this.licenses = licenses;
    }
}
```

This is the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="licenseclassmenue" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="select license"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{licenseCodes.licenses}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the screenshot

[image]

As you can see it is working.

### Update

I have forgot to add `@SessionScoped` annotation while testing. Now after adding it also worked.

Comment: what's your application server? I have the same code and it won't show any values of the fields.

Comment: I have uploaded the project here http://www.filefactory.com/file/741zot4kto1n/n/LicenseCode.zip. The server is JBoss AS7. What server are you using?

Comment: Same here. I have a second bean , user, placed in ANOTHER PACKAGE. I have no problems reading fields here. Could this be the reason? License enum and LicenseCodes share the same package.

Comment: I don't think package has any issue. Try to clean the server and rebuild the war file.

Comment: doesn't jboss/eclipse rebuilt the .war file every time I shutdown and reboot jboss?

Comment: Restarting the server sometimes don't build the war. I have faced similar situation before. In that case I stop the server; delete the war from the deployment; Export as War from Eclipse to the deployment directory; and run the server.

Comment: Deleted Project.war. Exported as .war to deployment folder. Jboss deployed .war file. Same issue. I will try to move the classes to the user package

Comment: did you tried to run the project that I have uploaded? is that worked?

Comment: I'm going to try this now. I'll give you feedback then, thanks.

Comment: Okay, your sourcecode works for me. When I copy the data to my project it won't work. I'll try to change my enumeration file

Comment: I noticed you have two libraries in your lib folder. jboss-jsf-api_2.1 and jsf_impl_2.1.7. Is it important to add them to the lib-folder?

Comment: These two jars are JBoss's Mojarra JSF 2. Infact if you package your war with jsf 2's other versions JBoss going to use it's own. I have create a user library with these two jars and while creating JSF2 project in eclipse I use these jars' reference. My war don't contain these jar. But for you I have put these into lib.

Comment: Your enum is fine. Cause I have copied your enum to the test app.

Comment: that means there is no obvious reason why this shouldn't work?

Comment: I created a new project and copied the files to it. Thank you Tapas Bose, everything is working now. :)